# Docker Compose: Change COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME without rebuilding the application

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Summary**:

I have an application X, I want to deploy multiple instances of the same application (port numbers will be handled by an .env) in the same OS without starting a `build` for each instance.

**What I tried**:

So I managed to dynamically (by the user changing .env file), change the `container_name` of a container. But then we cannot run 5 instances at the same time (even if the ports are different, docker just stops the first re-creates the container for second)

Next I came across `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` that seems to work BUT starts a new build.

---

**COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=hello-01**

```
docker-compose up
Creating network "hello-01_default" with the default driver
Building test
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 113a43faa138
Step 2/2 : RUN echo Hello
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba846acc19e5
Successfully built ba846acc19e5
Successfully tagged hello-01_test:latest
WARNING: Image for service test was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating hello-01_test ... done
Attaching to hello-01_test
hello-01_test exited with code 0
```

---

**COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=hello-2**

```
docker-compose up
Creating network "hello-02_default" with the default driver
Building test
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 113a43faa138
Step 2/2 : RUN echo Hello
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba846acc19e5
Successfully built ba846acc19e5
Successfully tagged hello-02_test:latest
WARNING: Image for service test was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating hello-02_test ... done
Attaching to hello-02_test
hello-02_test exited with code 0
```

---

**Source files**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    container_name: "${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_test"
    build: .
```

**.env**

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=hello-02
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN echo Hello
```

---

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
docker-compose version 1.21.2, build a133471
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By changing the container name without providing an `image:` reference the compose file has no idea that you've already built that image. So if you build that docker image as some local image `example/image/local, you can add`image: example/image/local`to your docker-compose file and do that to spawn`docker-compose up -d` many times by changing the name with an environment variable in your example.

However, it appears that you might want to look into using replicas instead of making this a horrifically manual effort outside of on the one-line full up that you'd get out of docker-compose.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax

Comment: what ever you said looks perfect, but I needed a quicker way so did `docker tag existing:latest new:latest` this way `build: .` thinks its already present so skip it

Comment: Isn't that only shuffling your tags around?

Comment: You might want to seriously consider replicas, depending on your usecase. But, 9 times out of 10 if you want multiple instances of a container you wanna use replicas.